# Drupal 7 db_query how to return regular array from varchar field

Tags: database

I am attempting to combine two arrays - one is stored in the database in a varchar field. Something like this.

```
["0","1","2","68","69","95","96","97","98","99","100"]
```

I am bringing in a similar array that comes from the front end.

```
["0","1","2","45","66","95","97","98","99","100"]
```

I need merging the two and remove duplicates.

```
   //merge post data and stored data
      $merge = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
      //remove duplicates
      $merge = array_unique($merge);
```

My problem is that when retrieving the `varchar` field, I am not getting a normal array but an associative. Here is my code.

```
$arr2 = db_query('SELECT stats FROM {my_db} WHERE uid = :uid AND nid = :nid', array(':uid' => $usid, ':nid' => $noid))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I need this to return a regular array, not an associative to combine the two and remove duplicates. Does anyone know how?

When I do a `print_r()` on `$arr2` it returns the following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [stats] => ["0","1","2","68","69","95","96","97","98","99","100"]
        )

)
```

I can't seem to be able to merge it and pass it to `array_unique()` on.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/node/1251174

```
$arr2 = db_query('SELECT stats FROM {my_db} WHERE uid = :uid AND nid = :nid', array(':uid' => $usid, ':nid' => $noid))->fetchCol();

print_r($arr2[0]);
```